# What's the Ruby equivalent of map() for strings?

Tags: ruby, split

If you wanted to split a space-separated list of words, you would use

```
def words(text)
    return text.split.map{|word| word.downcase}
end
```

similarly to Python's list comprehension:

```
words("get out of here")
```

which returns `["get", "out", "of", "here"]`. How can I apply a block to every character in a string?

Comment: Do you want `map` method to use? or any block ?

Comment: I don't know your need. As you might be confused by yourself about your need. Otherwise you could answer my question quickly. See, how many way, you can use block. `"aaa".each_char { |c| #code }` or `"aaa".scan(/./) { |c| #code }` etc..  More better answer you could get, if you can tell what the *real* operation you are going to perform inside a block. If it is a *upcasing each character* `"abc".gsub(/./,&:upcase)` or *downcasing* then ``"abc".gsub(/./,&:downcase)``

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use `String#chars`:

```
irb> "asdf".chars.map { |ch| ch.upcase }
  => ["A", "S", "D", "F"]
```

Comment: Close, but I want to return a string. Can I do that without appending `.join("")` to your solution?

Comment: @EMBLEM what is your need, can you bit specific in your post?

Comment: @ArupRakshit I want to apply a given operation to every character in a string and return the string.

Comment: @EMBLEM after splitting it into a word ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit No, that was just an example. It has nothing to do with what I'm actually asking.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is `"asdf".gsub(/./) { |ch| ch.upcase }`, but it's kind of ugly/confusing. `"asdf".chars.map(&:upcase).join` is better IMO.

Comment: @JeremyRuten what OP asked, I don't get it.. any help please.

Comment: You may wish to use `String#each_char` (returns an enumerator) rather than `String#chars` to avoid the creation of an intermediate array.

Answer (score 10):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
class String
  def map
    size.times.with_object('') {|i,s| s << yield(self[i])}
  end
end

"ABC".map {|c| c.downcase}       #=> "abc" 
"ABC".map(&:downcase)            #=> "abc"
"abcdef".map {|c| (c.ord+1).chr} #=> "bcdefg"
"abcdef".map {|c| c*3}           #=> "aaabbbcccdddeeefff"
```

Answer (score 4):

I think the short answer to your question is "no, there's nothing like `map` for strings that operates a character at a time." Previous answerer had the cleanest solution in my book; simply create one by adding a function definition to the class.

BTW, there's also `String#each_char` which is an iterator across each character of a string. In this case `String#chars` gets you the same result because it returns an Array which also responds to `each` (or `map`), but I guess there may be cases where the distinction would be important.

Comment: Re `chars` vs. `each_char`, the rule is straightforward: use the former for `Array` methods, the latter for `Enumerable` methods. It grates when I see `chars` with an `Enumerable` method, as it creates an unnecessary temporary array.

Comment: Aha, I forgot that `Enumerable` doesn't go through that extra step. Arrays are enumerable; Enumerables are not arrays.  Thanks.